# Docker connectivity issue with gRPC

Tags: docker, grpc

I am on Windows 10 Pro working with Docker for Windows. I am trying to put together a simple nodejs client server based on the [gRPC greeter example for NodeJS](http://www.grpc.io/docs/quickstart/node.html). I end up with this error.

> console.log('Greeting:', response.getMessage());
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMessage' of undefined at
>   Object.callback (/usr/src/app/static_codegen/greeter_client.js:51:38
>   at /usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:420:14

I installed hping3 in the container in the role of the client and it can connect to the localhost port 50051 of the container in the role as the server.

```
root@8aca5f26c64f:/usr/src/app# hping3 localhost -p 50051
HPING localhost (lo 127.0.0.1): NO FLAGS are set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes
len=40 ip=127.0.0.1 ttl=64 DF id=906 sport=50051 flags=RA seq=0 win=0 rtt=9.9 ms
len=40 ip=127.0.0.1 ttl=64 DF id=934 sport=50051 flags=RA seq=1 win=0 rtt=9.8 ms
len=40 ip=127.0.0.1 ttl=64 DF id=985 sport=50051 flags=RA seq=2 win=0 rtt=9.7 ms
len=40 ip=127.0.0.1 ttl=64 DF id=1068 sport=50051 flags=RA seq=3 win=0 rtt=9.6 ms
len=40 ip=127.0.0.1 ttl=64 DF id=1094 sport=50051 flags=RA seq=4 win=0 rtt=9.6 ms
```

I am also using the node container used in the [grpc-docker-library](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-docker-library/tree/master/1.0/node).

Can anyone point me to some tips on how to troubleshoot this further please?

Scott